# Prove that the limiting value of the sequence is $\pi/6$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the limit of the sequence $$ a_n = \sum _{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{(4n^2 - i^2)^{1/2}}.$$

I know that $\frac{n}{\sqrt{(3n^2)}} \gt a_n \gt \frac{n}{\sqrt{4n^2 - 1}}$, and therefore $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \gt a_n \gt \frac{1}{2}$.

I don't think proceeding this way will give the limiting value of the sequence but I don't know what else to do here.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the sum as approximating an integral?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. This is a duplicate question, someone linked the original question which has an answer. Thanks for the help though.